# Converting SQL where CASE query to Yii2 Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have been trying to convert the below SQL query to a yii based active records query with andWhere but no luck

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE `role` = 1
AND (CASE users.type WHEN 'admin' THEN users.admin_id ELSE users.member_id END IN ('94', '56', '173', '172', '50', '67', '57', '86', '53', '93', '39', '40', '171', '175', '136', '160', '145', '177', '156', '88', '125', '176', '157', '120', '165', '116', '103', '107', '149', '134', '146', '92', '164', '82', '148', '111', '78', '77', '151', '87', '129',, '29', '62'))
```

Comment: How far have you gotten? What is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'users' table is represented by User class model:

```
User::find()->where(['role' => 1'])->andWhere("(CASE users.type WHEN 'admin' THEN users.admin_id ELSE users.member_id END IN ('94', '56', '173', '172', '50', '67', '57', '86', '53', '93', '39', '40', '171', '175', '136', '160', '145', '177', '156', '88', '125', '176', '157', '120', '165', '116', '103', '107', '149', '134', '146', '92', '164', '82', '148', '111', '78', '77', '151', '87', '129',, '29', '62'))")->all();
```